# Append Single Quote to Comma Separated Data Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to append single quotes to data which is comma separated

I have a variable which stores the data as follows

```
1234,1234,1234,1234,1234
```

I need to to add single quotes to appear as follows

```
'1234','1234','1234','1234'
```

I wrote the following simple query

```
declare @id VARCHAR(155);
set @pid = '1234,1234,1234';

select concat(char(39),concat(@id,',',''''))
```

Comment: i doubt this question is about MySQL as MySQL does not even allow `declare @id VARCHAR(155);` in plain statements.  This more looks like SQL Server (MSSQL) valid syntax.

Comment: @RaymondNijland but Microsoft SQL Server uses `+` for string concatenation, not `concat()`

Comment: *" Microsoft SQL Server uses + for string concatenation, not concat()"* not totally true as  SQL Server 2012+ also supports [CONCAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  @BillKarwin

Comment: Well, thanks for the info. It's also true that Microsoft allows `declare` to be used with a variable with an `@` sigil, while MySQL does not. You may be right, the OP may be using Microsoft, and they mistakenly tagged the question [tag:mysql]. We'll probably never know, because their low reputation score shows they are a drive-by user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace()` and `concat()`:

```
concat('''', replace(@pid, ',', ''','''), '''')
```

The `replace()` adds the single quotes around each comma.  The `concat()` adds them at the beginning and end.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d4d1d90c4b834fd218791b20cd0004c) is a db<>fiddle.